# MongoDB schema pattern Performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

i am not sure about which NoSQL MongoDB schema i should choose.
let us say i have collection of patients and collection of doctors. each patient may subscribe for some doctors.
should i store doctors ids inside patients collection or the opposite which is storing patients ids inside doctors collection, or both?
basically i am asking about performance issue specially about the read.
1- doctor can see all info about their patients
2- patients can also see all info about their doctors

i have tried storing doctors ids inside patients collection because it is highly unlikely for a patient to subscribe for lot of doctors.

but the problem is that i think doctors will have some slowness because the system will try to filter doctor's id in every patient document, and precisely its array of ids in each patient document.